# Maze algorithm generates pattern

Tags: c++, recursion, backtracking, maze

I want to implement the Maze generation algorithm in C++ using recursive backtracking.

My code is fully working, kinda... I always get an output with the same pattern.

**Maze dimension 2 output:**

```
XXXXXX
X    X
X XX X
X XX X
X    X
XXXXXX
```

**Maze dimension 4 output:**

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX
X          X
X XX XX XX X
X XX XX XX X
X          X
X XX XX XX X
X XX XX XX X
X          X
X XX XX XX X
X XX XX XX X
X          X
XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I thought this was because I used a for-loop in my recursive function (genereerDoolhof()) and it somehow generated multiple paths; but this doesn't seem to be the problem.

Than I thought because the algorithm didn't stop when it hit the start-position, but also this wasn't the problem.

I'd rather expect an output where the maze starts at point A, and ends at point A. And where it looks more random, and not so patterned.

**My Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> //for shuffle
#include <cstdlib> //for rand()
#include <time.h>  //for time
#include <iomanip> //for hex
using namespace std;


struct Positie{
    int rij; int kolom;
};

struct Cel{
    bool muurLinks, muurRechts, muurBoven, muurOnder;
    bool bezocht;
};

typedef vector<vector<Cel>> Doolhof;

//Code voor weergave doolhof, bijvoorbeeld gebruike cout << doolhof
//Elke cell wordt weergegevendoor 3 X 3 keer ofwel X ofwel _
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const Doolhof& doolhof){
    //Print per doolhof rij, drie rijen tekstueel
    for(auto row: doolhof){
        for(const Cel& Cel: row){
            if(!Cel.muurBoven)
                stream << "X X";
            else
                stream << "XXX";
        }
        stream << endl;
        for(const Cel& Cel: row){
            if(!Cel.muurLinks && !Cel.muurRechts)
                stream << "   ";
            else if(!Cel.muurLinks)
                stream << "  X";
            else if(!Cel.muurRechts)
                stream << "X  ";
            else if(!Cel.muurOnder || !Cel.muurBoven) //important: if left/right is closed, but top or down isnt'
                stream << "X X";
            else
                stream << "XXX";
        }
        stream << endl;
        for(const Cel& Cel: row){
            if(!Cel.muurOnder)
                stream << "X X";
            else
                stream << "XXX";
        }
        stream << endl;
    }
    stream << endl;
    return stream;
}

//My Functions (definition)
Doolhof maakDoolhof(int dimensie);
Cel& getCel(Doolhof& doolhof, Positie positie);
vector<Positie> getGeldigeBuren(Doolhof& doolhof, Positie positie);
void murenWegTussenBuren(Doolhof& doolhof, Positie cel1, Positie cel2);
void genereerDoolhof(Doolhof& doolhof, Positie pos, bool debug);


//MAIN:
int main() {
    //Dimension of doolhof
    int n = 4;

    //Variable for Doolhof
    Doolhof doolhof;
    doolhof = maakDoolhof(n);

    //Set last parameter to 'true' for seeing all steps
    genereerDoolhof(doolhof, {0,0}, false);

    cout << doolhof;


    return 0;
}

//My Functions (declaration)
//
//Creates the bases of a doolhof (no cells connected yet)
//param dimensie: Int -> Dimension of the doolhof
//return: type=Doolhof -> Returning the whole Doolhof
//Signature: Int -> Doolhof
Doolhof maakDoolhof(int dimensie) {
    //Vector for Doolhof
    Doolhof doolhof;

    for (int i = 0; i < dimensie; i++) {
        //Vector to hold all the cels making one row
        vector<Cel> row;

        for (int j = 0; j < dimensie; j++) {
            //Creating a Cel and it's properties
            Cel cel;
            cel.muurLinks = true;
            cel.muurRechts = true;
            cel.muurBoven = true;
            cel.muurOnder = true;
            cel.bezocht = false;

            //Adding cel to row
            row.push_back(cel);
        }

        //Adding row to whole doolhof
        doolhof.push_back(row);
    }

    //Returning doolhof
    return doolhof;
}

//Returns Cell at specified position
//param doolhof: Doolhof& -> Reference to the Doolhof vector
//param positie: Positie -> Position of Cell to return
//return: type=Cel& -> Reference to the cell at specified position
Cel& getCel(Doolhof& doolhof, Positie positie) {
    //Parameters to local variables
    int row = positie.rij;
    int col = positie.kolom;

    return doolhof[row][col];

    /*
    WRONG
    This is for 1 dimensional vector... 
    //Getting dimension by taking length of first row :P
    int dimension = doolhof[0].size();

    //Formula to get index of cell in the Doolhof-vector
    //(row - 1) * dimensionOfDoolhof + col
    int indexOfCell = (row - 1) * dimension + col;

    //Returning element on indexOfCell
    return doolhof[indexOfCell]
    */
}

//Returns all the valid cells around the specified position
//Cells laying out of the maze ain't valid for example
//param doolhof: Doolhof& -> Reference to the Doolhof vector
//param positie: Positie -> Positie of the cell to check
//return: type=vector<Positie> -> Vector containing all valid positions
vector<Positie> getGeldigeBuren(Doolhof& doolhof, Positie positie) {
    //Vector holding valid positions of cells
    vector<Positie> valid;

    //Dimension
    int dimension = doolhof[0].size();

    //Position to add
    Positie pos;

    //Checking for horizontal cells
    //Check if left is valid
    if (positie.kolom - 1 >= 0 &&
        positie.kolom < dimension &&
        positie.rij < dimension &&
        positie.rij >= 0) {
        pos.rij = positie.rij;
        pos.kolom = positie.kolom -1;

        //Getting cel
        Cel cel = getCel(doolhof, pos);
        if(!cel.bezocht) valid.push_back(pos);
    }
    //Check if right is valid
    if (positie.kolom + 1 < dimension &&
        positie.kolom >= 0 &&
        positie.rij < dimension &&
        positie.rij >= 0) {
        pos.rij = positie.rij;
        pos.kolom = positie.kolom +1;

        //Getting cel
        Cel cel = getCel(doolhof, pos);

        if(!cel.bezocht) valid.push_back(pos);
    }

    //Checking for vertical cells
    //Check if upper is valid
    if (positie.rij - 1 >= 0 &&
        positie.rij < dimension &&
        positie.kolom < dimension &&
        positie.kolom >= 0) {
        pos.rij = positie.rij -1;
        pos.kolom = positie.kolom;

        //Getting cel
        Cel cel = getCel(doolhof, pos);

        if(!cel.bezocht) valid.push_back(pos);
    }
    //Check if bottom is valid
    if (positie.rij + 1 < dimension &&
        positie.rij >= 0 &&
        positie.kolom < dimension &&
        positie.kolom >= 0) {
        pos.rij = positie.rij +1;
        pos.kolom = positie.kolom;

        //Getting cel
        Cel cel = getCel(doolhof, pos);

        if(!cel.bezocht) valid.push_back(pos);
    }

    return valid;
}

//Takes away walls between specific cells
//param doolhof: Doolhof& -> Reference to the doolhof-vector
//param cel1: Positie -> Position of the first cell
//param cel2: Positie -> Position of the second cell
//return: void
void murenWegTussenBuren(Doolhof& doolhof, Positie cel1, Positie cel2) {
    //Variable for cells we're talking about
    Cel cel_a = getCel(doolhof, cel1);
    Cel cel_b = getCel(doolhof, cel2);

    //Case 1: HORIZONTAL -> cel2 <> cel1
    if (cel1.rij == cel2.rij &&
        cel1.kolom == cel2.kolom +1) {

        cel_a.muurLinks = false;
        cel_b.muurRechts = false;
    }
    //Case 2: HORIZONTAL -> cel2 <> cel1
    else if (cel2.rij == cel1.rij &&
             cel2.kolom == cel1.kolom +1) {

        cel_a.muurRechts = false;
        cel_b.muurLinks = false;
    }
    //Case 3: VERTICAL -> cel1 ^ cel2
    else if (cel1.rij == cel2.rij +1 &&
             cel1.kolom == cel2.kolom) {

        cel_a.muurBoven = false;
        cel_b.muurOnder = false;
    }
    //Case 4: VERTICAL -> cel2 ^ cel1
    else if (cel1.rij +1 == cel2.rij &&
             cel1.kolom == cel2.kolom) {

        cel_a.muurOnder = false;
        cel_b.muurBoven = false;
    }
    //Case x: ERROR, just return
    else return;


    //Setting the cell-values back in doolhof
    getCel(doolhof, cel1) = cel_a;
    getCel(doolhof, cel2) = cel_b;

    return;
}

//Generates the final doolhof (takes away walls & connects cells,...)
//param doolhof: Doolhof& -> Reference to the doolhof
//param positie: Positie -> Position to do recursion on
//param debug: Bool -> Prints iteration-steps when true
//return: void
void genereerDoolhof(Doolhof& doolhof, Positie pos, bool debug) {
    //Get cell from position
    Cel cell = getCel(doolhof, pos);

    //Cel = visited
    getCel(doolhof, pos).bezocht = true;

    //Get valid neighbours
    vector<Positie> valid;
    valid = getGeldigeBuren(doolhof, pos);

    //If no valid neighbours
    if (valid.size() == 0) return;

    Positie validPos;
    for (int i = 0; i < valid.size(); i++) {
        validPos = valid[i];
        murenWegTussenBuren(doolhof, pos, validPos);
        genereerDoolhof(doolhof, validPos, false);
    }

    //Printing out all iteration steps when debug == true
    if (debug) cout << doolhof;
}
```

It's a very big code; but I documented everything well using comments.
I'm pretty sure the problem lays in the last function (genereerDoolhof), this is the recursive backtrack function; however I'm not sure of course.

Because my code contains some Dutch I'll explain all the functions here as well.

**Short explanation of all functions:**

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const Doolhof& doolhof)
```

Ignore this, this is just to be able to do `cout << doolhof;`

- **Doolhof** means 'maze' to start
- **Doolhof maakDoolhof()** Just puts all cells into the maze, with the cells default values (all walls are true and set, and visited by the 
  recursion is false)
- **Cel& getCel()** You can give a position/coordinate in the maze, and the cell - including it's properties - will be returned
- **vector getGeldigeBuren()** This function gets all the valid neighbours of a cell, to be sure the algorithm stays in the
  maze; and it doesn't include 'neighbors outside of the maze'
- **void murenWegTussenBuren()** Each cell consists out of 3x3 X's, this function takes two cells and connects them. If cellA is located 
  right of cellB, cellA.wallLeft is taken a way, and at cellB.wallRight
  is taken away (set to false), so they are connected.
- **void genereerDoolhof()** recursive backtrack-algorithm, this function should mix all the previous functions to make a nice maze.

I think I'm very close implementing the Maze-algorithm, I just need the last bit of logic and helping hand to fully solve it. I'd be very thankful for your help!

*The function genereerDoolhof(.., .., true) contains a 'debug-mode', set the last parameter to true to see all the steps and iterations.*

**EDIT:**
I edited my code, the problem now is that I get the error 'Segmentation fault' at runtime;

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> //for shuffle
#include <cstdlib> //for rand()
#include <time.h>  //for time
#include <iomanip> //for hex
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

struct Positie{
    int rij; int kolom;
};

struct Cel{
    bool muurLinks, muurRechts, muurBoven, muurOnder;
    bool bezocht;
};

//Stack holding positions
std::stack<Positie> myStack;

typedef vector<vector<Cel>> Doolhof;


//Code voor weergave doolhof, bijvoorbeeld gebruike cout << doolhof
//Elke cell wordt weergegevendoor 3 X 3 keer ofwel X ofwel _
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const Doolhof& doolhof){
    //Print per doolhof rij, drie rijen tekstueel
    for(auto row: doolhof){
        for(const Cel& Cel: row){
            if(!Cel.muurBoven)
                stream << "X X";
            else
                stream << "XXX";
        }
        stream << endl;
        for(const Cel& Cel: row){
            if(!Cel.muurLinks && !Cel.muurRechts)
                stream << "   ";
            else if(!Cel.muurLinks)
                stream << "  X";
            else if(!Cel.muurRechts)
                stream << "X  ";
            else if(!Cel.muurOnder || !Cel.muurBoven) //important: if left/right is closed, but top or down isnt'
                stream << "X X";
            else
                stream << "XXX";
        }
        stream << endl;
        for(const Cel& Cel: row){
            if(!Cel.muurOnder)
                stream << "X X";
            else
                stream << "XXX";
        }
        stream << endl;
    }
    stream << endl;
    return stream;
}

//My Functions (definition)
Doolhof maakDoolhof(int dimensie);
Cel& getCel(Doolhof& doolhof, Positie positie);
vector<Positie> getGeldigeBuren(Doolhof& doolhof, Positie positie);
void murenWegTussenBuren(Doolhof& doolhof, Positie cel1, Positie cel2);
void genereerDoolhof(Doolhof& doolhof, Positie pos, bool debug);
void debug_output(const Doolhof& doolhof, Positie pos);

//MAIN:
int main() {
    //DEBUG MODE, set true to debug
    const bool DEBUG = true;


    //Dimension of doolhof
    int n = 10;

    //Variable for Doolhof
    Doolhof doolhof;
    doolhof = maakDoolhof(n);

    //Seeding random function
    srand(time(0));
    //Random start position
    int random_rij = rand() % n;
    int random_kolom = rand() % n;

    Positie startPos;
    startPos.rij = random_rij;
    startPos.kolom = random_kolom;

    //Launch function to generate doolhof
    genereerDoolhof(doolhof, startPos, DEBUG);

    //Printing out doolhof
    cout << doolhof;

    return 0;
}

//My Functions (declaration)
//
//Function to show each iteration
//param doolhof: const Doolhof& -> Reference to the vector doolhof
//param pos: Positie -> Position of the current location
void debug_output(const Doolhof& doolhof, Positie pos) {
    int rij = 0;
    for(auto row: doolhof){
        for(const Cel& Cel: row){

            if(!Cel.muurBoven)
                cout << "X X";
            else
                cout << "XXX";
        }
        cout << endl;
        int kolom = 0;
        for(const Cel& Cel: row){
            char sep = ' ';
            if (pos.rij == rij && pos.kolom == kolom) sep = 'S';


            if(!Cel.muurLinks && !Cel.muurRechts)
                cout << " " << sep << " ";
            else if(!Cel.muurLinks)
                cout << " " << sep << "X";
            else if(!Cel.muurRechts)
                cout << "X" << sep << " ";
            else if(!Cel.muurOnder || !Cel.muurBoven) //important: if left/right is closed, but top or down isnt'
                cout << "X" << sep << "X";
            else {
                sep = 'X';
                if (pos.rij == rij && pos.kolom == kolom) sep = 'S';
                cout << "X" << sep << "X";
            }
            kolom++;
        }
        cout << endl;
        for(const Cel& Cel: row){
            if(!Cel.muurOnder)
                cout << "X X";
            else
                cout << "XXX";
        }
        cout << endl;

        rij++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return;
}

//Creates the bases of a doolhof (no cells connected yet)
//param dimensie: Int -> Dimension of the doolhof
//return: type=Doolhof -> Returning the whole Doolhof
//Signature: Int -> Doolhof
Doolhof maakDoolhof(int dimensie) {
    //Vector for Doolhof
    Doolhof doolhof;

    for (int i = 0; i < dimensie; i++) {
        //Vector to hold all the cels making one row
        vector<Cel> row;

        for (int j = 0; j < dimensie; j++) {
            //Creating a Cel and it's properties
            Cel cel;
            cel.muurLinks = true;
            cel.muurRechts = true;
            cel.muurBoven = true;
            cel.muurOnder = true;
            cel.bezocht = false;

            //Adding cel to row
            row.push_back(cel);
        }

        //Adding row to whole doolhof
        doolhof.push_back(row);
    }

    //Returning doolhof
    return doolhof;
}

//Returns Cell at specified position
//param doolhof: Doolhof& -> Reference to the Doolhof vector
//param positie: Positie -> Position of Cell to return
//return: type=Cel& -> Reference to the cell at specified position
Cel& getCel(Doolhof& doolhof, Positie positie) {
    //Parameters to local variables
    int row = positie.rij;
    int col = positie.kolom;

    return doolhof[row][col];    
}

//Returns all the valid cells around the specified position
//Cells laying out of the maze ain't valid for example
//param doolhof: Doolhof& -> Reference to the Doolhof vector
//param positie: Positie -> Positie of the cell to check
//return: type=vector<Positie> -> Vector containing all valid positions
vector<Positie> getGeldigeBuren(Doolhof& doolhof, Positie positie) {
    //Vector holding valid positions of cells
    vector<Positie> valid;

    //Dimension
    int dimension = doolhof[0].size();

    //Position to add
    Positie pos;

    //Checking for horizontal cells
    //Check if left is valid
    if (positie.kolom - 1 >= 0 &&
        positie.kolom < dimension &&
        positie.rij < dimension &&
        positie.rij >= 0) {
        pos.rij = positie.rij;
        pos.kolom = positie.kolom -1;

        //Getting cel
        Cel cel = getCel(doolhof, pos);
        if(!cel.bezocht) valid.push_back(pos);
    }
    //Check if right is valid
    if (positie.kolom + 1 < dimension &&
        positie.kolom >= 0 &&
        positie.rij < dimension &&
        positie.rij >= 0) {
        pos.rij = positie.rij;
        pos.kolom = positie.kolom +1;

        //Getting cel
        Cel cel = getCel(doolhof, pos);

        if(!cel.bezocht) valid.push_back(pos);
    }

    //Checking for vertical cells
    //Check if upper is valid
    if (positie.rij - 1 >= 0 &&
        positie.rij < dimension &&
        positie.kolom < dimension &&
        positie.kolom >= 0) {
        pos.rij = positie.rij -1;
        pos.kolom = positie.kolom;

        //Getting cel
        Cel cel = getCel(doolhof, pos);

        if(!cel.bezocht) valid.push_back(pos);
    }
    //Check if bottom is valid
    if (positie.rij + 1 < dimension &&
        positie.rij >= 0 &&
        positie.kolom < dimension &&
        positie.kolom >= 0) {
        pos.rij = positie.rij +1;
        pos.kolom = positie.kolom;

        //Getting cel
        Cel cel = getCel(doolhof, pos);

        if(!cel.bezocht) valid.push_back(pos);
    }

    return valid;
}

//Takes away walls between specific cells
//param doolhof: Doolhof& -> Reference to the doolhof-vector
//param cel1: Positie -> Position of the first cell
//param cel2: Positie -> Position of the second cell
//return: void
void murenWegTussenBuren(Doolhof& doolhof, Positie cel1, Positie cel2) {
    //Variable for cells we're talking about
    Cel cel_a = getCel(doolhof, cel1);
    Cel cel_b = getCel(doolhof, cel2);

    //Case 1: HORIZONTAL -> cel2 <> cel1
    if (cel1.rij == cel2.rij &&
        cel1.kolom == cel2.kolom +1) {

        cel_a.muurLinks = false;
        cel_b.muurRechts = false;
    }
    //Case 2: HORIZONTAL -> cel2 <> cel1
    else if (cel2.rij == cel1.rij &&
             cel2.kolom == cel1.kolom +1) {

        cel_a.muurRechts = false;
        cel_b.muurLinks = false;
    }
    //Case 3: VERTICAL -> cel1 ^ cel2
    else if (cel1.rij == cel2.rij +1 &&
             cel1.kolom == cel2.kolom) {

        cel_a.muurBoven = false;
        cel_b.muurOnder = false;
    }
    //Case 4: VERTICAL -> cel2 ^ cel1
    else if (cel1.rij +1 == cel2.rij &&
             cel1.kolom == cel2.kolom) {

        cel_a.muurOnder = false;
        cel_b.muurBoven = false;
    }
    //Case x: ERROR, just return
    else return;


    //Setting the cell-values back in doolhof
    getCel(doolhof, cel1) = cel_a;
    getCel(doolhof, cel2) = cel_b;

    return;
}

//Generates the final doolhof (takes away walls & connects cells,...)
//param doolhof: Doolhof& -> Reference to the doolhof
//param positie: Positie -> Position to do recursion on
//param debug: Bool -> Prints iteration-steps when true
void genereerDoolhof(Doolhof& doolhof, Positie pos, bool debug) {

    //Initial cel current cell
    Positie currentCel = pos;

    //If debug mode is on
    if (debug) debug_output(doolhof, pos);

    //Vector holding positions of unvisited neighbours of cell
    vector<Positie> unvisited;
    unvisited = getGeldigeBuren(doolhof, currentCel);

    if (unvisited.size() > 0) {
        //Randomly unvisited neighbours
        int r = rand() % unvisited.size();
        Positie chosen;
        chosen = unvisited[r];

        //Push the current cell to the stack
        myStack.push(currentCel);

        //Remove wall between current and chosen
        murenWegTussenBuren(doolhof, currentCel, chosen);

        //Make chosen current and make it visited
        currentCel = chosen;
        getCel(doolhof, currentCel).bezocht = true;

        //Recursive call
        return genereerDoolhof(doolhof, currentCel, debug);

    } else {
        if (myStack.size() != 0) {
            myStack.pop();
            currentCel = myStack.top();

            return genereerDoolhof(doolhof, currentCel, debug);
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: What you expect to get as output? Random mazes are usually generated using pseudorandom numbers. Your code doesn't.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Edited my question, I do now

Comment: Yes, now it likely does crash because you pop() last element of stack and then try to access its top(). Your article still does not explain ... what you expect from us? What is your question?

Comment: @ÖöTiib Thanks a lot! Now it's fully working! I was just wondering how to make my algorithm work, if you put your comment in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I think you should ask mr Hofkens these questions ;D

Comment: @SamApostel Don't want to bother him with basic questions like this ;)